# Not receiving any data from my robot

Tags: ros, image-raw, topics, ardrone, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Main Problem

I am currently trying to check if I am getting any data from the *ARDrone 2.0* that I have on my desk. It is connected to the wifi and I can do a *roslaunch ardrone_autonomy ardrone.launch*. However, since my executable listener node was not receiving any camera feed, I decided to check the data myself on `rqtplot`. To my shock, no data was appearing on the `rqt_plot` in terms of the topic `/ardrone/bottom/image_raw`. When I check the other image feeds, I got the same lack of data being published, even though `rqt_plot` can subscribe to these topics.

I even tried running:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/ardrone/bottom/image_raw
```

But am getting no output (the window just shows what's behind it). How should I go debugging this ?

### NOTE

I also noticed the fact that the terminal where I launch rqt_plot, I get the notes of the type:

```
TopicCompleter.update_topics(): could not get message class for topic type "ardrone_autonomy"/Navdata on topic "/ardrone/navdata"
```

And so on for every other topic besides the camera feeds. Does this have anything to do with the problem?

### Environment

Currently working on a Raspberry Pi 3, with ROS-Kinetic installed on an Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS. I had to manually build the project using `catkin_make` and downloading this special repository of https://github.com/PhilippeMorere/ardronelib.git, since the normal repository does not work for ARM architectures.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253020/not-receiving-any-data-from-my-robot/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a simple problem where the `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` hasn't been sourced as of yet. Once this is done, all the message classes will be completed.

---

Originally posted by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) with karma: 83 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0